# "cannot find -lOpenCL" error when making the Cuda SDK

Tags: nvidia, libraries, opencl

I have an ASUS Notebook with nVidia gt 520m and thought about trying some OpenCL programming (first time) on Ubuntu 11.10. I installed the nvidia-current-dev package. Thus, I found libOpenCL.so and such in /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ folder:

```
$razvan@...:~$ locate libOpenCL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so.1.0
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so.1
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so.1.0
/usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so.1.0.0
```

I then installed the CUDA Toolkit for Ubuntu 10.10 from nVidia website and also the NVIDIA GPU SDK (in /opt/gpu_sdk).

When I go to /opt/gpu_sdk/OpenCL and try the make command I get:

```
razvan@...:/opt/gpu_sdk/OpenCL$ make
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/gpu_sdk/OpenCL/common'
a - obj/release/oclUtils.cpp.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/gpu_sdk/OpenCL/common'
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/gpu_sdk/shared'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/gpu_sdk/shared'
make -C src/oclConvolutionSeparable/
make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/gpu_sdk/OpenCL/src/oclConvolutionSeparable'
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../..//OpenCL//bin//linux/release/oclConvolutionSeparable] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/gpu_sdk/OpenCL/src/oclConvolutionSeparable'
make: *** [src/oclConvolutionSeparable/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Afeter installing the nvidia-current-dev package I went to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and made nvidia-current.conf where I specified /usr/lib/nvidia-current and /usr/lib32/nvidia-current. Then I used ldconfig for caching the new locations.

Needless to say, it didn't work. I also appended the /usr/lib/nvidia-current and /usr/lib32/nvidia-current to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in the hope of working... it did not work.

Comment: I found out by myself what the problem was. I was trying to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which is related to /usr/bin/ld specifically, while I should have set `LIBRARY_PATH` which is the correct environment variable for the gnu compiler (used here). I don't know the connection between `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` (or in this case `ld` and `gcc` and why `gcc` doesn't use the `ld` executable.. I thought that gcc is using it; but maybe someone experienced enough can answer that).

Answer (score 3):

Cannot set LD_LIBRARY_PATH which is related to /usr/bin/ld specifically.

Should have set LIBRARY_PATH which is the correct environment variable for the gnu compiler (used here).

Whatever the connection between LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH (or in this case ld and gcc and why gcc doesn't use the ld executable..

Answer (score 2):

Look here for a good explanation of `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250666)

`LIBRARY_PATH` is checked when compiling, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` upon program execution.